# TinyMCE inserting image - wrong path

Tags: tinymce

When im trying to insert image with path like this:

```
/wombat/htdocs/web/icon.png
```

after insert its being converted to:

```
../../../icon.png
```

why? What part of code is doing it? How to disable it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

By default TinyMCE converts URLs to relative URL. You need to set the [relative_urls](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3arelative_urls) config item to false.

Comment: I can't believe I've spent 2 hours on this! Thank you sir!

Comment: I can't believe I spent 2 hours on this!  Thank you sir!

Comment: Why ?? Whyyyyy ?? Thanks ! Great. Simple. Works. I upvote the question as well.